# runtime store example

Tags: blackberry

Can any one give me a example of how to use the runtime store in blackberry?

I get the data from xml, shown below.

Can any one give me sample code to store the following node data into the runtime store and access these values in other classes?

```xml
                <upcomingmeeting id="2">
                    <starttime>02:00pm </starttime>
                    <companyname>Qtech Software</companyname>
                    <meetingtype>New Agent</meetingtype>
                    <meetingwith>
                         <person>Yogesh</person>
                         <person>Mahesh </person>
                         <person>Ganesh </person>
                     </meetingwith>
                     <meetingnote>
                         <information>Yogesh good</information>
                         <information>Yogesh 1 bad</information>
                     </meetingnote>
                </upcomingmeeting>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Read the article [Storing objects nonpersistently](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Storing_objects_nonpersistently_1219788_11.jsp) carefully.

Following two sections of the above article will show how to store a `String` object on `RuntimeStore` and retrieve the object later.

[Code sample: Storing a String in the runtime store](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/CS_Storing_a_string_in_the_runtime_store_1554332_11.jsp)

[Code sample: Getting a stored String from the runtime store](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/CS_Getting_a_stored_string_from_the_runtime_store_1554333_11.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn parsing XML first 
Follow this link that how can you parse a XML from Http Request.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901822/xml-parsing-using-sax-for-blackberry/11914662#11914662
```

While parsing XML you can parse it data to a Vector , Create this Vector in a seperate class by which you can access its value to any other class too.