# InputStream exceptions while processing xml-code

Tags: blackberry, io

hi am trying tp parse the xml in blackberry that stores in server. But it comes out in inputstream line with different exceptions.mostly with Datagram Protocol and TcpInput exceptions.i have attached my code here kindly guide me.

```java
try {
    Document doc;
    StreamConnection conn = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    conn = (StreamConnection) Connector.open("http://xyz.com/GetImageDetails.xml;deviceside=true;");

    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    docBuilderFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
    docBuilderFactory.setCoalescing(true);

    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    docBuilder.isValidating();
    is = conn.openInputStream();
    doc = docBuilder.parse(is);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("IMG_URL");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
        Node textNode = list.item(i).getFirstChild();
        System.out.println(textNode);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: try with  this Connector.open("http://xyz.com/GetImageDetails.xml"+ ";deviceside=true" ) ;

Comment: yep also tried with that, am getting out in InputStream line.and also checked with connection in simulator it is connected with WIFI.help me

Comment: @Pramodhini. As you are using HTTP try for more specialized connection type. Try for HttpConnection rather using  StreamConnection

Comment: @Pramodhini The same code  for  Rss  HTML file worked for me...

Comment: @Nilachala is correct ...please try with HttpConnection and let us know the result ..

Comment: Hai i have changed an than also it dosent run. it shows XMLParser$UTF8InputStreamReader.nextChar().

Comment: no its not running for me.guide me

Comment: have you tried XMLDemo example in Blackberry sample application ..

Comment: ya its a static stored xml.i wanna read from url and when reading it shows like Data gram protocol received is null like.

Comment: i got response xml while parsing it throws exception like org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Expecting an element.help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
The XML parsing class is
/***/
```

package com.application.xmlParser;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory;

import com.application.log.Log;

public class CopyOfXMLParser extends DefaultHandler {

```
private String RecordElement;
private String xmlURL;
private Hashtable newObj = new Hashtable();
private Vector Records = new Vector();
private CallBack callBack ;
private String _localEndTag = "";

public void ParseInputStream(String stream,String rootElement, String recordElement , CallBack callBack) 
{
    RecordElement = recordElement;
    this.callBack = callBack;

    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.getBytes());
    try 
    {
        XMLReader reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
        reader.setContentHandler(this);
        reader.parse(new InputSource(in));
    } 
    catch ( Exception e ) 
    {
        System.out.println("#### ##### Parse Exception : " + e + "#### #####" + xmlURL);
      /*  callbackAdapter.callback(Records);*/
    }
}


public void startElement(String Uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException 
{
}

public void characters(char [ ] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException 
{
   String elementValue = new String(ch, start, length).trim();

    Log.d("End Tag", _localEndTag); 
    Log.d("Tag Value ", elementValue);  

    if(_localEndTag ==  null || _localEndTag.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        newObj.put((String)_localEndTag, (String)elementValue);
    }
}

public void endElement(String Uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException 
{
    _localEndTag = localName;

    if ( localName.equalsIgnoreCase(RecordElement) ) 
    {
        Records.addElement(newObj);
        callBack.callBack(Records);
        System.out.println("###### ###### FINISH ###### ######" +RecordElement);
    }
}
```

}

```
/***/

/***/
How to Implement

take the (Http)InputStream response into String  and call the below method ..your problem is solved 

new CopyOfXMLParser().ParseInputStream(new String(baos.toByteArray()) ,"SOAP:Envelope", "SOAP:Envelope");
```

I am getting all the elements value , with this code 
    /***/

Comment: Boss i wanna read directly form url not in some stored place.pls guide me

Comment: @Pramodhini you are getting InputStream from your above mentioned code pass the InputStream refreance to this method
new CopyOfXMLParser().ParseInputStream(InputStream is ,String rootElement, String recordElement, CallbackAdapter callbackAdapter) 
..will give you parse result

Comment: i got response xml while parsing it throws exception like org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Expecting an element.help me

Comment: can you let me know the xml url..?

Comment: hi here is my sample one just check and help with some progress.  http://124.247.204.176:8082/Sample1.xml  check this soap url.thanks.

Comment: @Pramodhini ...I have solved your xmL parsing mystery ...follow the new answer

Comment: hi very very thanks for your concern am getting the values. Again how to get for a particular different tag names. and how to use it in another pages.thanks

Comment: i have edited again the above code ..you will get all the data in HashTable . You just need to create a interface and Implement this according to your need ..

Comment: hi it compares the element value with wrong local end tag. how to use if condition and check it for a particular tag and get that element value.thanks ya its very useful for me.

Comment: new CopyOfXMLParser().ParseInputStream(new String(baos.toByteArray()) ,startTag, endTag);
startTag = Starting tag of the xml , endTag = End tag of the xml  ... send startTag ,end Tag values in this method according to the xml's start/End tags .. that you are parsing  ,you will get proper result ..!!!

Comment: hi again for one tag its mismatching , so all tag are getting mismatched. Like for tuple there is no value,but its showing assert numbers value.like that all tags are mismatched.am too trying it.

Comment: Hi also how can the use the hash table as interface and get values in other BB screens.guide pls

Answer (score 0):

USe Sax parsing For XML Parsing. 
Refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901822/xml-parsing-using-sax-for-blackberry/11914662#11914662

Comment: hi this code breaks in httpconnection.getresponsecode and throws Datagram protocol error.this also not works it freaks me out.